# Create empty file, prompting if the file already exists?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

How can I touch or create new file with the script asking me a question if I want to overwrite the file if it already exists? What should the script look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  How are you going to get the file name (command line argument or prompt)?  How do you read the file name, or how do you get the command line arguments?  Which command tests whether a file exists?  How do you create a file?  What does the noclobber option do?  Does it help?  What have you tried?  _Especially_ what have you tried?  Do you know where the [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) manual is? Have you read it yet?  Would it be a good idea to do so?  (Answer to that: maybe not — but soon you should.)

Comment: Please share your progress on this what you have written and what error you have faced as explained by Jonathan Leffler. Help is for those who first help themselves. We learn from our mistakes but first you have to do the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    echo "Want to overwrite? (Y/n)"
    read ANSWER
    [ "$ANSWER" = "Y" ] && touch "$1" || echo "Ok"
else
    echo "Creating"
    touch "$1"
fi
```

Calling it as: `./script <filename>`

Comment: Note that `touch` does not overwrite an existing file; it changes the 'last modified' time on the file without damaging its contents.

Comment: You might also observe that `[ x = y ] && touch x || echo OK` echoes 'OK' and `[ x = x ] && touch z || echo OK` touches (creates) `z` and echoes nothing.  It isn't clear what the 'OK' means, therefore ('OK; I didn't touch the file', I think; the message could be clearer).